# Linux server imported into GCE with CloudEndure not working

Tags: linux, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I imported a remote Linux server into Google Compute Engine using their inbuilt import tool (CloudEndure). The sync was successful however I'm not able to connect to the google server. I have also provided my firewall rules below. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
Name    Source tag / IP range / Subnetworks Allowed protocols / ports   Target tags

0.0.0.0/0   tcp:1500    ce-replicator

default-allow-http 0.0.0.0/0    tcp:80  http-server

default-allow-https 0.0.0.0/0   tcp:443 https-server

default-allow-icmp 0.0.0.0/0    icmp    Apply to all targets

default-allow-internal 10.128.0.0/9 tcp:0-65535, udp:0-65535, 1 more    Apply to all targets

default-allow-rdp 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:3389    Apply to all targets

default-allow-ssh 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:22  Apply to all targets
```

Answer (score 0):

ce-replicator server is private to CloudEndure. You can not login this server. If import progress is end, you can create on cloud for imported machine and you can connect to your replicated machine via SSH.

Comment: Then how do I connect to this server and make this server live?

Comment: Which one that you mean? your replicated from onprem? If it is, you create on cloudendure's console. If ce-replicator is closed, I think you have to start from scratch for migration process.

Answer (score 0):

When you install CloudEndure agent on a server, the data from that server is being replicated to ce-replicator server in GCP. Once the data is replicated, you can see that in CloudEndure portal, you can run a test/cutoff machine which will then create a copy of your server in GCP and then you'll be able to login to it.